# How can i do the same as shown in the gif in Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

I can select a word and press CTRL+D in Sublime Text 3 to get the occurrences of the same word in the document. I can't find a way to do the same in VS IDE.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the gif because of firewall issues at the moment, but I believe what you're trying to do is select a word, and then navigate to the next occurrence of that word.

The equivalent in Visual Studio is not *as* straight-forward as Sublime, however, it's still possible. Whenever you double-click (select) a word in Visual Studio you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the **Quick Find** dialog and it will auto-populate the Find field with whatever word you have selected. From there, you can keep pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> to jump to the next occurrence. The benefit of this is that you have the ability to specify whether to jump to the next selection in the current document, current project, current solution, or all open documents -- So it gives you a little extra flexibility.